# What should I do when a NAA flag has been marked helpful although the answer hasn't been deleted?

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer

I had downvoted and flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31219059/3049655) as NAA. For the curious <10K users (since the answer is going to be deleted because of the "meta-effect"), the answer is

> hey this code is working fine and one more thing can you provide information what exactly you want the result for example what result u r expecting from this code??

The answerer had deleted the answer for a short period of time and this caused my flag to be marked as 'helpful'. Then, the answerer undeleted the answer. I tried to flag it as NAA again but could not as I've already done so.

**What should I do in such cases?**

The upvotes on the answer also seems suspisious....

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The OP had undeleted the post after it was deleted from review.

Moderators are [auto-alerted by a Community flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/165773) when this happens, so there is not anything you need to do in this case.

I've re-deleted the post. When a moderator deletes a post, the OP can no longer undelete it.

Comment: Ok. That's Cool! Why don't you close the question too? It is basically "_Here's a wall code, please explain the cause of the error and how to remove it_"

Comment: I didn't pay much attention to the question; community voting was well under way. Cast the last vote.

Comment: I didn't know this. Good feature!

Comment: Surprising that the OP can undelete the post if the community via at least three people has deleted it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Given how inaccurate <20k LQP reviewers are, I think that's fine. If (one? three?) trusted user(s) votes to delete (rather than recommend deletion), undeletion is not possible unilaterally.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - It was something I questioned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226993/answers-deleted-via-recommend-deletion-votes-in-review-should-not-be-undeletable , but interestingly enough since then I've observed that most of the answers being undeleted have actually been fixed before doing so. Most of the people undeleting their posts have taken reviewer comments to heart and converted non-answers into full ones, some of surprisingly good quality. The rest we can remove based on the system flags.

Comment: @BradLarson: That's really good to hear.